# The Social Action Responsibility and Heroism Act (England and Wales)

Tags: civil-law, scotland, emergencies, good-samaritan, northern-ireland

Is there an equivalent law in SCOTLAND and NORTHERN IRELAND to [The Social Action Responsibility and Heroism Act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/3) (England and Wales)?

Answer (score 3):

just found this when I had a similar question of my own so thought I would share the response I got:
no there isn't a Scottish equivalent to the English SARHA.
And there has been some criticism of it:

- https://www.modernlawreview.co.uk/january-2017/my-legislation-copy-4/
- https://www.bristollawreview.com/single-post/2018/06/12/is-sarah-heroic-at-all
- https://www.lexisnexis.co.uk/blog/dispute-resolution/whats-the-point-of-the-social-action-responsibility-heroism-act